Different types of prepositions
Why is it wrong to say "I parked my car along your"?
To me it is okay and implies that cars havr to placed parallelly. Whereas if I used "next to" they wouldn't need yo be parallel.

I think it should be "yours" meaning your car.

That idea would be expressed by I parked my car alongside yours.

Please be mroe csarfel with puncutation. [on purpose so the OP sees what is meant]. Prepositional phrases require objects.
